# Looping certain parts of code within a loop and adding a simplenamespace and a int

Tags: python

```
import random
import types

attribute = types.SimpleNamespace()
attribute.C1strength= "10"
attribute.C1skill="10"  
attribute.C2strength="10"
attribute.C2skill="10"  
attribute.counter=""

attribute.counter=1

characterNameOne=str(input("Please input first character's name"))    
characterNameTwo=str(input("Please input second character's name"))
print("The characters have 2 attributes : Strength and Skill")  
print ("A 12 and 4 sided dice are rolled")
print("Each character is set to 10")
print("The number rolled on the 12 sided dice is divided by the number rolled on the 4 sided dice")
print ("The value of the divided dice is added to the character's attributes")

for counter in range (attribute.counter): 
    dieOne = random.randint(1,4)
    dieTwo = random.randint(1,12)
    divisionValue= dieTwo/dieOne
    divisionValue= round(divisionValue,0)
    x=int(divisionValue)
    int(x)
    x=(x-0)

    print(x)

    attribute.C1strength = (attribute.C1strength + str(x))
    print(characterNameOne)
    print("Your strengh value is :",attribute.C1strength)

    attribute.C1strength += str(x)
    print("Your skill value is :",attribute.C1skill)


    attribute.C1strength += str(x)
    print(characterNameTwo)
    print("Your strengh value is :",attribute.C2strength)

    attribute.C1strength += str(x)
    print("Your skill value is :",attribute.C2skill)

fileObj = open("CharacterAttributes.txt","w")  
fileObj.write('Charcter one ,your strength:' + str(attribute.C1strength) + '\n')
fileObj.write('Character one, your skill:' + str(attribute.C1skill) + '\n')
fileObj.write('Character two),your strength:' + str(attribute.C2strength) + '\n')
fileObj.write('Characte two), your skill:' + str(attribute.C2skill) + '\n')
fileObj.close()
```

Hi this is my code , 
I want the character attributes to start at 10 and then the (divisionValue) is then added . The only problem i have is i want the divisionvalue to be added to each charcter's attributes and it adds the digits such as 10 + 1 = would equal 101. 
Also , the division value should be different each time so the process should be called each time it is needed . Sorry if my code is wrong , I've just started out on python . Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In order to concatenate two integers, you would do the following

```
x = 10
y = 1
z = str(x) + str(y)
```

Which will give you '101', and if you need to treat that as an int, just do

```
z = int(str(x) + str(y))
```

Not quite sure what you mean by the 2nd half of your question.

You may want to wrap your `for` loop in a function, and pass it the`divisionValue`. This will allow you to call it multiple times with different `divisionValue` values.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are adding string instead of numbers. Just make sure you use integers of the initial strength and skill values and don't apply the `str()` calls to `x` when updating those values.